# Trackchanges line display in pdf for OFFICE-MAC while using office-js

Tags: macos, office365, pdf-generation, office-js

Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Pdf, { sliceSize: 65536 }, function (result) { });

In Windows (Word 2016 & office 365) this works correctly, but on Mac (Word for Mac) the track changes lines are visible.
[image]
I want to remove that line using office-js.

Let me know if any one have clue on that.
Happy Coding & Share!